# Slow performance of PyTorch Categorical

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I have been using a PPO (Proximal Policy Optimisation) architecture for training my agent in a custom simulator. My simulator has become quite fast as it is written in Rust. The speed of my inner loop is therefore bottlenecked by some functions that are inside the PPO agent.

When I profiled the function with pyinstrument it showed that most of the time is spent on initialising the Categorical class and calculating the log probabilities.

I hope someone can help and if there is a faster way to do this using PyTorch.

```py
    def act(self, state):
        action_probs = self.actor(state)
        dist = Categorical(action_probs)

        action = dist.sample()
        action_logprob = dist.log_prob(action)

        return action.detach(), action_logprob.detach()

    def evaluate(self, state, action):
        """Evaluates the action given the state."""
        action_probs = self.actor(state)
        dist = Categorical(action_probs)

        action_logprobs = dist.log_prob(action)
        dist_entropy = dist.entropy()
        state_values = self.critic(state)

        return action_logprobs, state_values, dist_entropy
```

[image: Pyinstrument showing the speed of the program.]

I have seen some other techniques to do this, but it was not very clear to me if they would inprove the speed.

Comment: is it a standalone function? or inside a class? I would try to define a global variable of the classifier, then it would be initiated only once

Comment: It is inside a class, but the Categorical is instantiated with action_probs. Is it possible to instantiate it without and then use it over and over again with different probabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into same problem a while back and implemented my custom `Categorical` class by copying from [pytorch source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/distributions/categorical.html)

It is similar to original code but removes unnecessary functionality. Does not require initializing class every time, instead initialize once and just use `set_probs()` or `set_probs_()` for setting new probability values. Also, it works only with probability values as input (not logits) but we can manually apply `softmax` on logits anyway.

```
import torch
from torch.distributions.utils import probs_to_logits
class Categorical:
    def __init__(self, probs_shape): 
        # NOTE: probs_shape is supposed to be 
        #       the shape of probs that will be 
        #       produced by policy network
        if len(probs_shape) < 1: 
            raise ValueError("`probs_shape` must be at least 1.")
        self.probs_dim = len(probs_shape) 
        self.probs_shape = probs_shape
        self._num_events = probs_shape[-1]
        self._batch_shape = probs_shape[:-1] if self.probs_dim > 1 else torch.Size()
        self._event_shape=torch.Size()

    def set_probs_(self, probs):
        self.probs = probs
        self.logits = probs_to_logits(self.probs)

    def set_probs(self, probs):
        self.probs = probs / probs.sum(-1, keepdim=True) 
        self.logits = probs_to_logits(self.probs)

    def sample(self, sample_shape=torch.Size()):
        if not isinstance(sample_shape, torch.Size):
            sample_shape = torch.Size(sample_shape)
        probs_2d = self.probs.reshape(-1, self._num_events)
        samples_2d = torch.multinomial(probs_2d, sample_shape.numel(), True).T
        return samples_2d.reshape(sample_shape + self._batch_shape + self._event_shape)

    def log_prob(self, value):
        value = value.long().unsqueeze(-1)
        value, log_pmf = torch.broadcast_tensors(value, self.logits)
        value = value[..., :1]
        return log_pmf.gather(-1, value).squeeze(-1)

    def entropy(self):
        min_real = torch.finfo(self.logits.dtype).min
        logits = torch.clamp(self.logits, min=min_real)
        p_log_p = logits * self.probs
        return -p_log_p.sum(-1)
```

Checking execution time:

```
import time
import torch as tt
import torch.distributions as td
```

First check inbuilt `torch.distributions.Categorical`

```
start=time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(50000):
    probs = tt.softmax(tt.rand((3,4,2)), dim=-1)
    ct = td.Categorical(probs=probs)
    entropy = ct.entropy()
    action = ct.sample()
    log_prob = ct.log_prob(action)
    entropy, action, log_prob
end=time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

output:

```
"""
10.024958199996036
"""
```

Now check custom `Categorical`

```
start=time.perf_counter()
ct = Categorical((3,4,2)) #<--- initialize class beforehand
for _ in range(50000):
    probs = tt.softmax(tt.rand((3,4,2)), dim=-1)
    ct.set_probs(probs)
    entropy = ct.entropy()
    action = ct.sample()
    log_prob = ct.log_prob(action)
    entropy, action, log_prob
end=time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

output:

```
"""
4.565093299999717
"""
```

The execution time dropped by a little more than half. It can be further reduced if we use `set_probs_()` instead of `set_probs()`.
There is a subtle difference in `set_probs()` and `set_probs_()` which skips the line `probs / probs.sum(-1, keepdim=True)` which is supposed to remove floating points errors. However, it might not be always necessary.

```
start=time.perf_counter()
ct = Categorical((3,4,2)) #<--- initialize class beforehand
for _ in range(50000):
    probs = tt.softmax(tt.rand((3,4,2)), dim=-1)
    ct.set_probs_(probs)
    entropy = ct.entropy()
    action = ct.sample()
    log_prob = ct.log_prob(action)
    entropy, action, log_prob
end=time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

output:

```
"""
3.9343119999975897
"""
```

You can check source code for pytorch distributions module on your machine some where at `..\Lib\site-packages\torch\distributions`